# What are the requirements for the green/gold crates to respawn in the game world?

Tags: scrap-mechanic

My understanding is that the damaged green/gold crates occasionally respawn in the game world and that there is a low chance of them being gold instead of green. However, what defines when this happens? Is it related to how far away you are from a certain area or is it perhaps time-based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as the map section unloads, it generates new crates in that area. The map loading distance depends on your visual settings.

Comment: If I were to put my view distance on the lowest, would this in theory cause crates to generate closer than if I were to have it on the highest setting?

Comment: @Oast Yes. Although slightly cheaty, you can turn down your view distance for a minute, turn it back up, and crates would've respawned.